# jQuery Form Validator showing ".validate is not a functon"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have tried to run the script severally but not successful. I used firebug to check the error, but its complaining about this line TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function (required: "Please enter a name")

**THIS IS MY SCRIPT**

```
<style type="text/css">  
 .errors {color:#900};  
</style>    
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>

$().ready(function() {


// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#feedback").validate({
errorClass:"errors",
    rules: {

        nameid: {
            required: true
        }
        },
    messages: {

        nameid: {
            required: "Please enter a name"

        }
    }
});

 });

 </script>
```

**THIS IS MY FORM**

```
<form id="feedback" name="form1" method="post">
              <p><strong>Fill the Form Below to get back to us</strong><br>
              </p>
              <table width="400" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="3">
                <tr>
                  <td>Name:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="name" id="nameid" placeholder="Enter Full Name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Email:</td>
                  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="emailid" placeholder="Enter Your Email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Phone:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phoneid" placeholder="Enter Your Phone #"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Message:</td>
                  <td><textarea name="message" id="msgid" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </form>
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `$().ready(function(...` where did you find that ? Secondly, did you include the validate plugin after you've included jQuery

Comment: Have you included the `validate.js` file?

Comment: i think you are missing to load the `validate` lib.

Comment: @adeneo it is right in the [jQuery's documentation for ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @epascarello - exactly, among the "not reccomended" ways to use it.

Comment: Both $(document).ready(function() and $().ready(function() works same way. I have changed it and its still the same error.
Also I have also included the jquery.js and jquery.validate.min.js in my site folder

Comment: It does, but the documentation specifically states that the latter is not reccomended, so why would you use it ?

Comment: Do you include the JavaScript file with the validate function?

Comment: Did you include `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` anywhere else on your page?

Comment: @KevinB i included that in my head section

Comment: that's not what i'm asking. Did you include it anywhere else other than what you have provided. In other words, did you include it twice, or three times. Based on your comment to the answer below, i'm assuming that answer is "Yes" which would explain why you are having problems.

Comment: @KevinB I did not include it anywhere else.

Comment: Add this both before and inside of your document.ready: `alert($.fn.jquery)` Are they both the same?

Comment: @KevinB Yes they are both the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what else you're loading in your project, but this usually happens with people working with popular CMS frameworks, that uses different plugins, etc creating a javascript conflict.

Have a read here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ about how to avoid this.

Your solution should be something like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {

    $(function() {

        $(document).ready(function() {


        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#feedback").validate({
        errorClass:"errors",
            rules: {

                nameid: {
                    required: true
                }
                },
            messages: {

                nameid: {
                    required: "Please enter a name"

                }
            }
        });

         });


    });

})(jQuery);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I have also tried this... The script shows no error, but it not working.
It only refreshes the page when i click the submit button

Comment: You reported the error and as suggested is now fixed! If you're script doesn't do what you want you need to change it. But the truth is the issue you reported as nothing to do with what your, now, working script is doing.  Please accept the answer, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You need to submit a new issue. But anyway to solve that, you nees to prevent the form event default from happening and then do whatever you want. You can find lots of examples online - I'm on mobile so I can't provide links atm, but it's easy.

Comment: You're welcome! About preventing the default event from happening ( http://api.jquery.com/submit/ )